# why python-docx is not found in

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

Trying to import docx module and installing it using both conda and pip
conda install python-docx
or pip install python-docx

But it is showing package not found error. See attached image
[image: error image]

Comment: Please don't post images of output. Instead, copy-paste the details into your question and format apropriately. You also only show part of the output and only for `conda install`. Not for `pip install`. Furthermore, you are missing details like python version, OS version etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post your error that you are getting with pip, I can only comment on the `conda install` problem. `python-docx` is not available from the default channels, but from `conda-forge`. So use this to install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-docx
```